# Entity Framework generate the wrong Query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an issue with Entity Framework.
It's generating a query which contains a column name that doesn't exist in the model.

Here is the model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Sungy.ETL.Models
{
    public class Data
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public List<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; }
        public List<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
        public List<Data> Affiliates { get; set; }
        public long Record_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Record_Id")]
        public Record Record { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the query that EF generate (I manage to get it by using an interceptor) :

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI';INSERT INTO `Data`(
`Name`, 
`Unit`, 
`Record_Id`, 
`ElectricMeter_Id`) VALUES (
@gp1, 
@gp2, 
18, 
NULL);
SELECT
`Id`
FROM `Data`
 WHERE  row_count() > 0 AND `Id`=last_insert_id()
-- @gp1: 'P' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 1)
-- @gp2: 'Watt' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 4)
-- Executing at 25/01/2020 12.22.47 +01:00
-- Failed in 137 ms with error: Unknown column 'ElectricMeter_Id' in 'field list'

Closed connection at 25/01/2020 12.22.47 +01:00
Disposed transaction at 25/01/2020 12.22.48 +01:00
```

My project is an Asp .NET project. And I am using MySQL as DB. I cant use EnsureCreate since it's not a Core project.
There was a variable ElectricMeter_Id in Data, but I removed it. And I don't know why EF continue to use it in its query.

I tried to clear and rebuild the project, but nothing changed.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: After the Changing model, do you update your database table columns by migration?!

Comment: I have created the Database manually. But when i try to update the DB by migration it gives me an error : Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Change your `DbName` in the connection string and try to create a new database by command `Update-Database`. I can't help you in this manner. because you problem is not clear enough

Comment: I tried to do as you said but the same error is back : Input string was not in a correct format. How can I precise my problem so you can help me ?

Comment: It's strange... I just looked at the migration file and in the 'Data' table creation there is a reference to ElectricMeter_Id, yet it s not in my model :